# Set value of multidimensional object

Tags: json, angularjs

I have created a model class with name registration.ts

```
export class CustomerRegistration{
    customer: {
        firstname : string;
        lastname : string;
        email: string;
    }
    password: string;
}
```

Then I have created a component and, in that component, I am trying to set value in above class

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomerRegistration} from 'src/app/classes/customer/registration';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-userregistration',
  templateUrl: './userregistration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userregistration.component.css']
})
export class UserregistrationComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
}
register = new CustomerRegistration();
hello(){
this.register.customer.firstname= 'Karan';
console.log(this.register);
}
}
```

But when I am trying to set value in firstname I am getting below error

> core.js:6456 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined
> (setting 'firstname')

How can I set value of first name?

Comment: Note that AngularJS and Angular are two very different frameworks. Please don't spam the tags with any tag that looks similar.

Comment: Also, JSON is a text format; you're just dealing with objects. And objects do not really have dimensions; you're just talking about nested object structures, not multidimensional objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your `customer` property should be instanciated. You can do it in your class constructor:

```
export class CustomerRegistration {
  constructor(){
  this.customer = {} as any;
  }
  customer: {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    email: string;
  };
  password: string;
}
```

Also, consider using an interfaces like:

```
export interface ICustomer{        
    firstname : string;
    lastname : string;
    email: string;
}

export interface ICustomerRegistration{
    customer: ICustomer;
    password: string;
}
```

Then in your component:

```
Register:ICustomerRegistration = {customer:{} as ICustomer} as ICustomerRegistration;
Register.customer.firstname = 'Karan';
```

Comment: What if I declare it as customer:{ firstname : string; lastname : string; email: string; }password: string; then how can I set value of first name, because if I use this.register.customer.firstname='karan' I am getting same error

Comment: Can you check updated model class and suggest?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `customer` property is basically an array, so you cant access the inside properties with dot (.) operator.

You have to access it with array index, like this:

```
this.register.customer[0].firstname= 'Karan';
```

Here 0 is an index that will change dynamically based index value.